# Trying to direct to a build profile page after sign up page in xcode.

Tags: ios, segue

So I am currently trying to build an iOS app that has a social aspect to it. So users will have their own profiles and what not. I am trying to direct straight from the sign up page to a build profile page. I am using parse.com as my backend for the time being. The simulator runs fine until I fill out the textfields and press the sign up button then it crashes saying "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid class name. Class names cannot start with an underscore."

Any ideas whats wrong with it?

```
- (BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)showBuildProfile sender:(id)sender {

        NSString *firstname = [self.firstNameField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSString *lastname = [self.lastNameField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSString *username = [self.userField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSString *password = [self.passwordField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSString *email = [self.emailField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        if ([firstname length] == 0 || [lastname length] == 0 || [username length] == 0 || [password length] == 0 || [email length] == 0) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:@"Make sure you fill in all of the information." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
            return NO;
        } else {
            PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
            newUser.username = username;
            newUser.password = password;
            newUser.email = email;

            newUser[@"first name"] = self.firstNameField;
            newUser[@"last name"] = self.lastNameField;


            [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
                if (error) {
                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alertView show];
                } else {
                    //Sign up the user.
                }
            }];
            return YES; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the text property of your textFields

```
newUser[@"firstName"] = self.firstNameField.text;
newUser[@"lastName"] = self.lastNameField.text;
// also notice I removed the spaces, spaces make me nervous.
```